# Не могу получить Instagram Business account ID через Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, instagram-api, facebook-graph-api

Следуя https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/?locale=ru_RU, я получаю доступ к своей странице, но не могу получить доступ к странице клиента, к которой у меня есть доступ как фейсбук-разработчика. То есть на этапе

```
curl -i -X GET \ 
"https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me/accounts?access_token={access-token}"
```

я получаю страницу только себя, а клиента - нет.

Мне не хватает каких-то разрешений?

Следуя ответу `@carlosrafaelgn` на подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709794/cant-get-instagram-business-account-id-through-facebook-graph-api), я пошел по пути  получения доступных бизнесов через запрос вида:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me/businesses?access_token=xxx
```

и потом - получение Id Инстаграм аккаунта. Здесь я получаю оба бизнеса (себя и клиента), но для клиента посредством запроса

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/BUSINESS_ID/instagram_business_accounts?access_token=xxx
```

Я получаю пустой ответ. то есть это: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете подсказать путь или причину?
*Может так оказаться, например, что приложение, к которому мне дали доступ, не привязано ни  к какой странице фейсбук?*

Comment: Дайте хотя бы ссылку на видео, в котором показано правильное подключение девелопер аккаунта который в последствии ТОЧНО получит доступ к инстаграм акаунту заказчика. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разрешил ситуацию путем получения прав администратора на аккаунт заказчика. Но понимаю, что это решение - временное, поскольку полный доступ програмисту к ресурсам заказчика нереален в повседневной ситуации.

Ожидаю на более "каноничный" ответ.